# Nuget package is not finding and/or using System.Security.Cryptography

Tags: c#, namespaces, nuget, libraries, system.security

I'm writing some nuget packages for personal development, and I'm having a few issues with dependencies. I'm writing a security package and I need `System.Security.Cryptography`, and I can add a using statement fine (when the navigation bar is on `Framework` and not `Client`), but as soon as I try to build I get lots of errors telling me that `Cryptography` doesn't exist in the `System.Security` namespace. Is it just that Nuget packages don't support System.Security? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Add reference System.Security to your solution and build solution then add System.Security.Cryptography to your solutions..Its works for me...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it doesn't work for me. I just ended up using a library then packing the dll.